# How to generate "random" points with some minimum distance between them

Tags: java

I'm trying to make program which generates "map" with points (cities). Generate only random cities(represented by a graph) isn't problem, but I need set some minimum distance between them (for example, that distance between cities is 5 and more).
It's about 3 000 cities, so I'm looking for some effective solution.

I can't devise how to solve it, so I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide the map into a grid of 10x10 squares then any point which is within five units of a given point will necessarily be within one of the four squares defined by (x +/- 5, y +/- 5).  It's possible that a 10x10 square might contain up to eight points, but checking each new point against four squares with at most eight points each may be faster than having to check it against thousands of other points.

The biggest thing you need to watch out for with this approach is that because the negative-number behaviors of the integer-division operator float-to-integer conversion operators were chosen to be easy for processors rather than useful for programmers, one must watch out for anomalies if some coordinates are positive and some are negative.  For example, if `x` is an `int` and one computes `int col = x/10;`, `col` will be zero for x values from -9 to +9 (meaning the box that contains point (0,0) will be almost twice as big in each dimension as they should be).  If coordinates may go negative, one must adjust them to be positive before performing the division.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about 3,000 cities, it's probably not *that* unreasonable to drop them into your map, and then check for your minimum distance criterion as you go along.  Checking time goes up as O(n), and the more points you have on the map already, the more likely you are to get a "collision."

How "random" do you need?  Can you get by if you divide your map into a grid of 5x5 squares, and put exactly one point randomly in the center 2.5x2.5 of the box?  That would be fast, and you wouldn't get any collisions.

It may be worth it to look into really how much randomness in the city positions you need.

Answer (score 0):

if you're program uses an x and a y axis you should refer to the distance formula. [Here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm) is a link to it. The [Circle Equation](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/ATC1/circlelesson.htm) may come in handy also. 
Think of your first city as the center of the circle. The second city with the minimal distance should lie on the circumference of the circle with the minimal distance being the radius of that circle. You have infinite number of possibilities of where the second city should be. But again, that's assuming that you are using an x and a y axis.